# 'AE' characters appearing as one character in Safari

Tags: html, ios, css, safari

I have a landing page http://79.170.44.127/watches-of-switzerland.co.uk/

When viewing this page on a browser the H1 is shown correctly:

[image: Chrome on Windows]

However, when viewing on Safari on iOS or OSX the H1 is shown with the AE appearing as one character:

[image: Safari on OS X El Capitan]

I've debugged it but can't work out why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that is a specific feature of the "Vanitas" font. Check out [this](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/reserves/vanitas/) site that explains the font and shows how it should render. Looks like that AE --> Æ is supposed to be there. I would suggest using a different font

Comment: Thanks @cocoa any reason can you think that it would be rendering differently in iOS and OSX?